# GET not working when trying to access web API

Tags: .net, iis, xmlhttprequest, webapi

I wrote a simple web API in .net and am running it on a site I created under IIS on Windows 10. If I put the URL into Chrome "https://localhost:64591/api/custom", the JSON delivers the records called from the database. No problem there.

I put that same URL into a `XMLHttpRequest` object and the `onload` event never happens. As a test I replaced the URL with an outside URL that I know works. The `onload` event fires off and the response object works. It seems like there's something going on with IIS and it's blocking the "get" request.

Below is the code. Here's the outside URL that works: https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films .....
There's definitely something up with access to the API through IIS.

```cs
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://localhost:64591/api/custom', true)
request.onload = function () 
{
  alert(this.response); 
}
request.send();
```

Comment: Does your local server send "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" back as part of the header?

Comment: Bingo!!! I checked and the problem is CORS. I can now perform GET and POST as long as I do it from the same server and not mention the server name in the string.

Comment: New problem....I want to set up CORS. Been doing some reading but can't figure out how to do it in iis. I'm running Windows 10 Home Edition. Is it restricted or am I missing something?

Comment: I'll write an answer first for you to accept (or not 8-), before I say I know nothing about IIS, as I only run webservers on Linux. This may help, though: https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html If it doesn't, you may want to ask it as a different question.

Comment: For now I'm ok with not having CORS but at some point I'll need it. Guess I'll cross that bridge when I get to it :)

Comment: It's easily googled, probably. Don't forget to do your voting, um, duties. Accepting an answer (mine or your own) will prevent this question remaining open.

Comment: I followed your link and added the code to my web.config file. Now I can reach the api from other servers! Woo-hoo! How do I "accept" or vote to close the question? hahaha...I've got nothing but questions :)

Comment: There is supposed to be a grey check mark next to each answer you can click to accept, and grey up/down arrows you can click to vote.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like this is a CORS issue. I can perform GET and POST from an html page as long as that page is coming from the same server as my web api and I don't mention the server in the string 'api/custom' as opposed to  'https://localhost:64591/api/custom'. I'm ok with this since I'm just practicing web api stuff. At some point though I have to learn how to configure the CORS module in iis.

Answer (score 0):

try this, works for me (im using a python server, if you want to see it too comment)

```
url="127.0.0.1"; // or your loaclhost etc
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Idan Rotbart. I used your code but am unfortunately still getting a status code of 0. Your code and my code work with this url,  https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films but get this.status == 0 when I use the url pointing to the localhost https://localhost:64591/api/custom

Comment: I think I know the problem. when connecting to the server, the browser send GET request with "/"- that means server should send as response html file. Now in your case, your server does not recognize /api/custom- you can try add it to your server code (after focusing the data to the actual data we need without all the packet information).

Comment: Hi Idan, looks like it's a CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

You very probably have a CORS problem.

Try to have the server send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` back as part of the header.

I know next to nothing about IIS, but [this](https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html) may help.

Comment: You're exactly right ocrdu! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!